# What devices does CBCentralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals() return?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-bluetooth

I want to check which Bluetooth Devices my iPhone is connected to. In order to do that, I use `CBCentralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals()` like this:

```
let connectedPerphs = centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: []);
```

My problem is that even if my iPhone is connected to a BluetoothDongle (it explicitly says "connected" in the settings), the list that is returned by `retriveConnectedPeripherals()` is always empty. Am I using the method in a wrong way or can it not be used to detect a bluetooth connection such as the connection to to my dongle? If the latter is the case, how can I detect that connection?

Comment: What sort of device is the dongle?  You can only work with Bluetooth Low Energy peripherals. You can’t work with legacy peripherals

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Well, what kind of peripheral is it?  What is it supposed to do? Can the LightBlue app from the App Store find the peripheral?

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear, `centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals` always return empty or `nil` value, If you are not passing any value into `serviceUUIDs`

## retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:)

> Returns a list of the peripherals (containing any of the specified
>   services) currently connected to the system.

**serviceUUIDs:**

> A list of service UUIDs (represented by [CBUUID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbuuid) objects).

## Update:

Unfortunately this the long way to do it. You can create `Array` of `CBUUID` statically then you can pass it to the method. Please refer below code.

```
let aryUUID = ["1800","18811"]
var aryCBUUIDS = [CBUUID]()

for uuid in aryUUID{
    let uuid = CBUUID(string: "1800")
    aryCBUUIDS.append(uuid)
}
let connectedPerphs = centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: aryCBUUIDS)
```

[List of available services](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/)

Comment: Unfortunately I can not find the answer anymore, but somewhere I read that passing ```[]``` will get you all devices. But if that is not the case, how do I get all devices? Or can I get a list with all CBUUIDs that I can then pass on?

Answer (score 0):

First, this works only with BLE devices, thus if your dongle is using a common BT you will not get it from here, but probably using `EAAccessoryManager` `var connectedAccessories: [EAAccessory]` method, but as far as I know your app must comply to MFI.
That is why is asking which service your devices are exposing as a filter.